# image url in linked resource

Tags: c#, image, uri

I want to embed a image from an url in c# mail, I tried using this code but it is not working

```
 LinkedResource logoHeader = null;
AlternateView av1 = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(strBody, null,   MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
logoHeader= new LinkedResource("some xyz.com");  
logoHeader.ContentId = "logoimage";
av1.LinkedResources.Add(logo);
```

Comment: whys it is not working, is it throwing some errors?

Comment: ya its giving an error as the given format is not supported , my url is like this https://some.example.com

Answer (score 11):

```c#
string image = "example.com/image.jpg";
var webClient = new WebClient();
byte[] imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(image);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
LinkedResource resource = new LinkedResource(ms, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AlternateView av = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(str,null,MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
LinkedResource lr = new LinkedResource("E:\\Photos\\hello.jpg",MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
lr.ContentId = "image1";
av.LinkedResources.Add(lr);
message.AlternateViews.Add(av);
```

Comment: i can able to embed image if the image link is in c ,d ,or e drive.  It is not working  if the image link is like https://www.google.co.in/images/317789.gif

Comment: embedded image is coming in outlook, but not coming in Outlook web access